# subprocess.Popen fails when called from within unittest, but works when called from __main__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have a program that lauches processes with subprocess.Popen, it works when called normaly, but not within unittest (the python unit test framework).

```
python tests.py 
/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py:942: ResourceWarning: subprocess 434608 is still running
  _warn("subprocess %s is still running" % self.pid,
ResourceWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s


class BaseTests(unittest.TestCase):
```

It even fails when the process does nothing fancy, as in the following test case:

```
    def testPopen(self):

        subprocess.Popen(
            ['bash', '-c', "script-with-infinite-loop.sh"],
            stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':


    unittest.main()
```

Note1: the purpose of the program is to launch process in the background, that are detached from the Python program. So waiting for the process to end would defeat the purpose.

#### Update

The detached process launching works with the following code:

```
with subprocess.Popen(
        ["nohup bash -c script-with-infinite-loop.sh &"],
        stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        shell=True) as p:

    p.wait()

    if p.returncode != 0:
        raise Exception("failed")
```

But fails silently when running under unittests, i.e. the process returns with p.returncode == 0, but it seems that *script-with-infinite-loop.sh* never gets launched. I can see it because within script-with-infinite-loop.sh I log to a file (with echo 'sometthing'> f) , and the file is never created.

Comment: A well written unit test should clean up after it finishes and should leave the environment is the exact same state that it was when the test started. What you have here is doesn't conform to this (general) expectation -- it spawns off a new process every single time someone runs the unit test. And this is why you see that warning. So, either: 1) Ignore the warning, or 2) Write unit tests such that they wait on the child.

Comment: This "non well written" test is a simplification of the real test, to reproduce the problem as succintly as possible. The real test does various checks on the process, it's actual work, and then kills it in the cleanup phase. The actual program launches multiple processes, so waiting for each in the test would not test the intended usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you never wait on the process, the unittest module enables *warnings* during tests to show you programming errors (such as zombie-ing a process like this)

the proper course of action is to wait on the process, either with `.wait()` or with `.communicate()` or to use the `subprocess.` `run` / `call` / `check_call` / `check_output` functions

alternatively, you could use the contextmanager form of `Popen`:

```py
with subprocess.Popen(...):
    pass
```

if you'd like to see the same set of warnings during normal execution, try `python -Wonce yourfile.py`

Comment: Thanks, the goal is to launch background processes that are detached from the Python program (and stay alive when the program ends). So waiting for the process to end would defeats the purpose.

Comment: then you want something like `nohup` -- also `bash -c script-with-infinite-loop.sh` is nonsense, that's not going to work in the terminal either, you either want `bash script-with-infinite-loop.sh` or you want `bash -c ./script-with-infinite-loop.sh`.  additionally if you're looking to create daemon processes you might want to look into something like `runit` / `systemd` / etc. which was designed to do what you're doing